# rails 6.1.4 ArgumentError: Unknown key: :table_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the error below after my rails upgrade from 6 to 6.1. on an association.

Unknown key: :table_name. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :counter_cache, :join_table, :index_errors, :ensuring_owner_was

This is the code in my model

```
has_many :cloud_provider_relationships, table_name: 'ecosystems_cloud_providers',
                                          class_name: 'EcosystemCloudProvider'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cloud_providers, through: :cloud_provider_relationships,
                          join_table: 'ecosystems_cloud_providers'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_many` never took a `:table_name` key as an argument. You can safely remove it. `:class_name` is enough to map rows from `cloud_provider_relationships` table to `EcosystemCloudProvider` class

you can check all available options here https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many